# Unable to update mappings in Solidity smart contract using Python

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I wrote a simple solidity contract to write and read from the contract. I followed `https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134720/execute-a-contract-function-from-web3-py` answer. However, when I run the contract using below Python code, it neither writes values into mapping structure nor retrieve values from functions. The contract mapping structure already has a few entries which are written during execution in remix IDE in sepolia test network. I want do the same thing using Python. Please find the code below and correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

```
from web3 import Web3, EthereumTesterProvider

provider_url = "https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/f9xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" # url of sepolia n/w provided by infura

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(provider_url))
print (w3.isConnected())
 
abi = '[{"inputs": [ {"internalType": "string", "name": "HPW", "type": "string"} ], "name": "retrieve_reg_details", "outputs": [ {  "components": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "NVID", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "teq_coff", "type": "uint256[]" }, { "internalType": "int256", "name": "degree", "type": "int256" }, { "internalType": "int256", "name": "Cv", "type": "int256" }, { "internalType": "int256", "name": "revoc_status", "type": "int256" } ], "internalType": "struct Reg_SC1.reg_struct", "name": "", "type": "tuple" } ], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "HPWi", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "string", "name": "NVID", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "uint256[]", "name": "teq_coff", "type": "uint256[]" }, { "internalType": "int256", "name": "degree", "type": "int256" }, { "internalType": "int256", "name": "Cv", "type": "int256" }, { "internalType": "int256", "name": "revoc_status", "type": "int256" }], "name": "store_reg_details", "outputs": [], "stateMutability": "nonpayable", "type": "function" }, { "inputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "", "type": "string" } ], "name": "store_veh_reg", "outputs": [ { "internalType": "string", "name": "NVID", "type": "string" }, { "internalType": "int256", "name": "degree", "type": "int256" }, { "internalType": "int256", "name": "Cv", "type": "int256" }, { "internalType": "int256", "name": "revoc_status", "type": "int256"}], "stateMutability": "view", "type": "function" }]'

acct_address = "0x87xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
sc_address = "0x4bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
private_key = "45xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(acct_address)

cont_instance = w3.eth.contract(address = sc_address, abi = abi) # creates an instance of contract

Chain_id = w3.eth.chain_id
print ("chainn__id is ", Chain_id)
call_function = cont_instance.functions.store_reg_details("veh3", "nd98d", [2,6,2], 6, 21, 1).buildTransaction({"chainId": Chain_id, "from": acct_address, "nonce": nonce})

signed_tx = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(call_function, private_key=private_key)

send_tx = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_tx)

print("tx receipt is ", tx_receipt)

get_latest_data = cont_instance.functions.retrieve_reg_details('veh1').call() # run 

print("Details of veh 1 is ", get_latest_data)
```

Below is my Solidity code

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

contract Reg_SC1 
{
    struct reg_struct
    {
       
       string NVID ;
       uint[] teq_coff ;
       int degree ;
       int Cv ;
       int revoc_status ;
    }

    uint256 number ;
    // string HPW ;

    mapping (string => reg_struct) public store_veh_reg ;

    function store_reg_details(string memory HPWi, string memory NVID, uint[] memory teq_coff, int degree, int Cv, int  revoc_status) public 
    {
        store_veh_reg[HPWi] = reg_struct(NVID, teq_coff, degree, Cv, revoc_status) ;
    }

    function retrieve_reg_details(string memory HPW) public view returns (reg_struct memory)
    {
        return store_veh_reg[HPW];
    }
}
```

Here is the output I get in terminal. I think the data values are not written into the contract. [image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the exact contract code used? One odd thing is you are writing `veh3` and reading `veh1`.

Comment: Sir, I already stored veh1 details from remix. It was successfully. Now I want read it from python code. So, I wrote veh1 in retrieve_reg_details call. veh3 details in store_reg_details call is a new entry I want to write from python. The code is exact contract I shared in this question. I just masked the acct_address, contract address, and my private key. Code is same. Thank you.

Comment: You shared the python code, but you haven't shared the solidity code.

Comment: Sorry. I updated solidity code in question.

Comment: Sir, I shared the solidity contract code in question. Please check ..

Comment: I don't see a problem with the contract, nor with the python script. The only problem it the one mentioned early: you write to 'vh3', and read from 'vh1'. You said that you wrote to 'vh1', that something I cannot verify. The only think I can say is that if you write and read the same id it should work.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I got the issue. Actually, when we pass a string as argument in transaction, we should enclose it in single quotes i.e., " 'veh1' " in my case. It worked for me.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, python accepts both single quotes `'` and double quotes `"` as string delimiters.