# python web3 error: Unknown Account

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix, web3.py

I am trying to update the state of a variable in the smart contract using python web3 library, when I call the function using the `transact` method, this error appears

`ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'unknown account'}`

And the account I am using actually exists in my geth blockchain

Here is my python code

```
from time import sleep
from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(r"http://127.0.0.1:8545"))

web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

print(web3.is_connected())

print(web3.from_wei(web3.eth.get_balance(web3.eth.accounts[0]), "ether"))

usersContract = web3.eth.contract(address="0x1fCD05eE0DE1D332375e236cE479F8E80627ca1E", abi='[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"adr","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"userName","type":"string"}],"name":"addUser","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"userAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint16","name":"reputation","type":"uint16"}],"name":"updateUserReputation","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"adr","type":"address"}],"name":"getUserNameOfAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"userAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"getUserReputation","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint16","name":"","type":"uint16"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]');

i = 0


while True:
    usersContract.functions.updateUserReputation(userAddress=web3.to_checksum_address("0xeBc8Db75a4E5EFa2d86dfB44C305A0A18E34a434"), reputation=i).transact()
    i += 1
    result = usersContract.functions.getUserReputation(web3.to_checksum_address("0xeBc8Db75a4E5EFa2d86dfB44C305A0A18E34a434")).call()
    print(result)
    sleep(1)
```

And my solidity code

```
contract ExampleUsers {
    
    mapping(address => User) users;

    function addUser(address adr, string memory userName) public {
        users[adr] = new User(adr, userName);
    }

    function getUserNameOfAddress(address adr) public view returns (string memory) {
        return users[adr].getUserName();
    }

    function getUserReputation(address userAddress) public view returns (uint16) {
        return users[userAddress].getUserReputation();
    }

    function updateUserReputation(address userAddress, uint16 reputation) public {
        users[userAddress].setUserReputation(reputation);
    }

    function updateUserName(address userAddress, string memory newName) public {
        users[userAddress].setUserName(newName);
    }

}
```

user contract

```
contract User {
    
    address userAddress;
    uint16 userReputation;
    string userName;

    constructor(address adr, string memory name) {
        userAddress = adr;
        userName = name;
        userReputation = 0;
    }

    function getUserAddress() public view returns (address) {
        return userAddress;
    }

    function getUserReputation() public view returns (uint16) {
        return userReputation;
    }

    function setUserReputation(uint16 reputation) public {
        userReputation = reputation;
    }

    function getUserName() public view returns(string memory) {
        return userName;
    }

    function setUserName(string memory name) public {
        userName = name;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution,

I needed to create a transaction and sign it using my private key, when I did that, everything worked fine

**NB: send a transaction only when calling a function that will change the state of your smart contract variables, if not, the function `call` can be used instead of `buildTransaction`**

Here is my solution

```
from web3 import Web3
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(r"http://127.0.0.1:8545"))

web3.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)

# get your smart contract instance

usersContract = web3.eth.contract(address=your_smart_contract_address_here, abi=your_smart_contract_abi_here);

# your checksum address

my_account_checksum_address = web3.to_checksum_address(your_account_address_here)

nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(my_account_checksum_address)
tx = {
'nonce': nonce,
'value': 0,
'gas': 2000000,
'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('50', 'gwei'),
"from": your_account_address_here
}

# create a transaction that will update the state of your contract variables based on the function you called

transaction = usersContract.functions.updateUserReputation(userAddress=my_account_checksum_address, reputation=i).build_transaction(tx)


# sign the transaction with your private key

signed_transaction = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(transaction, private_key=your_account_private_key_here)

# send the transaction

send_tx = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)

# wait for the transaction to be added to the blockchain


tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(send_tx)
```

two useful links:

[Execute a contract function from web3.py](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134720/execute-a-contract-function-from-web3-py)

https://cryptomarketpool.com/send-a-transaction-to-the-ethereum-blockchain-using-python-and-web3-py/